# ASP.NET MVC + EF 4.3.1 + DbContext - some null associations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with EF 4.3.1, and the "EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C#" extension.  I'm using the repository pattern.

The problem I'm having is that EF is not populating associations in some cases where I would expect it to.  Is there something I need to do to trigger the population of all associations?

For example, I have an Assignment model that contains the properties "CompanyPartyId" and "EmployeePartyId".  Both these properties have FKs to Parties.PartyId.  That causes two associations to exist, Party (pointing to the Party specified by CompanyPartyId) and Party1 (pointing to the Party specified by EmployeePartyId).

For some reason, after saving a new Assignment, and retrieving it, the Party association is null.  Both CompanyPartyId and EmployeePartyId properties are set to values which exist in Parties.PartyId.  I have a similar issue with several other properties/associations; the properties are not null and contain valid values, but the association is null.

If it's relevant, Assignment uses a composite key; CompanyPartyId, EmployeePartyId, AssignmentTypeCode, and AssignmentStartDate.

The code in my controller looks like this (omitting validation and irrelevant logic):

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "assignment_edit")]
public ActionResult Create(AssignmentViewModel assignment)
{
    var newAssignment = assignment.NewAssignment;
    partiesRepository.SaveAssignment(newAssignment);

    var savedAssignment =
        partiesRepository.Assignments.First(x => x.CompanyPartyId == newAssignment.CompanyPartyId &&
                                                 x.EmployeePartyId == newAssignment.EmployeePartyId &&
                                                 x.AssignmentTypeCode == newAssignment.AssignmentTypeCode &&
                                                 x.AssignmentStartDate == newAssignment.AssignmentStartDate);
    var companyPartyId = savedAssignment.CompanyPartyId; // 1
    var companyParty = savedAssignment.Party; // null
    var employeePartyId = savedAssignment.EmployeePartyId; // 2
    var employeeParty = savedAssignment.Party1; // not null

    return View("Index");
}
```

The repository code is simple:

```
public IQueryable<Assignment> Assignments
{
    get { return _context.Assignments; }
}

public void SaveAssignment(Assignment assignment)
{
    var data = (from a in _context.Assignments
                where a.CompanyPartyId == assignment.CompanyPartyId
                      && a.EmployeePartyId == assignment.EmployeePartyId
                      && a.AssignmentTypeCode == assignment.AssignmentTypeCode
                      && a.AssignmentStartDate == assignment.AssignmentStartDate
                select a);
    if (!data.Any())
    {
        _context.Assignments.Add(assignment);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using eager loading, i.e. `get  { return _context.Assignments.Include("Party"); }`?

Comment: Juraj: I have not, I will see if I can work around the problem with .Include().

Comment: Juraj: I just tried this.  Using eager loading (Specifying .Include("Party")) does cause the association to be populated.  However, I'd like to remain using lazy loading if possible.  In my code above, how could I trigger the lazy loading to "kick in" and retrieve the required data?

Comment: The `Party` property must be declared as `virtual` in the POCO class. Also check whether `_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled == true`.

Comment: I can confirm that both of these conditions are true; Party is declared as "public virtual Party Party { get; set;}" in the generated Assignment class, and _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled == true.